# Issue with Telerik MVC grid using AJAX binding and the MVC Authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-mvc

I am using the Telerik MVC grid, together with AJAX binding to actions secured by [Authorize].

When the asp.net logged in session expires, if I trigger one of the grid actions, I get the following error message: "Error!The requested URL did not return JSON"

I want the ajax called actions to time out as a normal action would once the session has expired.

Any ideas? I've asked this a couple of times on the Telerik forums but have had no reply as yet.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer on the telerik forums.

I customised the Grid Error client side event: [link](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-error-handling-function-not-being-invoked.aspx) **<--dead link**

**Edit:** As the above link is dead, here is a code snippet. Hopefully it will help.
I used this on the Grid declaration:

```
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnError("onGridError"))
```

and this is the javascript function it calls which simply supresses the error and redirects to the login page:

```
function onGridError(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var xhr = e.XMLHttpRequest;

    document.location.href = '../Account/Login';
}
```

Note: I don't think the middle line (var xhr...etc) actually does anything, looks redundant to me, just grabbed it from the codebase.

Comment: Can you post the code here - the forum seems to be shut down.

Comment: @HitLikeAHammer added a snippet of code, hopefully this helps